# How to Define 1D and 2D Arrays Accurately

Tags: python, arrays

I know what 1D (1 - Dimensional) and 2D (2 - Dimensional) arrays are, but I don't know how to describe them.

---

e.g. A 2D array is data in a table ***- Needs more detail***

---

###### [This link](https://www.rose-hulman.edu/class/csse/csse221/current/Capsules/Summaries/07ArraysAndArrayListsSec2.pdf) can help you if you do not know what 1D and 2D arrays are. I am not allowed to use the wording of these definitions, however.

Comment: Maybe try looking online for a good definition?  Python doesn't have 'arrays' (natively) do you mean arrays or lists?  a 'Table' is not a good analogy.  There are no rows and columns in a list or array, they can represent rows and columns but don't need to.

Comment: @EliHarold I do not think that "data points" is allowed, however.

Comment: @JeffUK do you have any valid sources?

Comment: @taylor.2317 what IS "allowed?"

Comment: @taylor.2317 where have you looked?  Did you find any explanations online that you don't understand?

Comment: @EliHarold I do not know, but I know that the word "data" is not allowed...

Comment: @JeffUK [This link](https://www.rose-hulman.edu/class/csse/csse221/current/Capsules/Summaries/07ArraysAndArrayListsSec2.pdf) says "1D arrays are just one row of values, while 2D arrays contain a grid of values that has several rows / columns." But you said "There are no rows and columns in a list or array"...

Comment: @taylor.2317 The values in an array could be thought of as 'rows and columns' like in a spreadsheet, but they are not rows and columns;  that analogy falls down when you have more than 2 dimensions in your array.

Comment: @JeffUK I didn't know that you could have more than 2 dimensions!

Comment: Why is this tagged 'python' if your reference material is about Java arrays?

Comment: @JeffUK I use 1D and 2D arrays in Portable Python Scripter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to say that a one dimension array is an array which holds a single set of data such as strings, numbers or objects.

A multi dimensional or a 2d array, an array contains another level of arrays inside.